# Lounge access at Marrakech airport

Tags: air-travel, airports, lounges, marrakech

Does Marrakech airport (RAK) have any lounge access where I can purchase a pass? I've had a look and could find a British Airways one, but as I'm flying RyanAir, I doubt I'd be able to get in and I don't think you can pay for a pass for this either. I'm happy to pay, but I just can't find the info.

Comment: The RAK (Marrakesh airport) lounge is no longer accessible to PriorityPass holders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one lounge only (Convives de marque, available in departures and in arrivals), the access can [bought directly at the lounge](http://www.onda.ma/Media/Files/Formule-individuelle3) for a fee of (24.000 Dhs).

Another way to buy the access can is from [prioritypass](https://prioritypass.com/) for $27 USD (single visit fee will be deducted from your standard membership balance which will cost you $99). You also can [make a reservation](http://bit.ly/1Je2Rye) directly from the official airport website, not sure how will you pay later, no information was given in the site about that.

Comment: Thanks, although the `sleepinginairports` link doesn't seem to have a the airport in the drop down

Comment: @jumpingcode updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, although it is worth mentioning in your answer that you have to pay for a membership and then are charged the $27USD for every visit.

Comment: @jumpingcode it seems that you can buy the access directly from the lounge, I updated the answer. The file is in French but that's what I understood from it.

Comment: 24,000 DHS is [approx $2,500 USD](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=24000+mad+to+usd) - that's the annual subscription (quoted 'TTC / An' = 'all taxes included, per year').

Comment: It appears that this lounge is no longer included in the Priority Pass program (it is not the in the Priority Pass directory).

Answer (score 2):

There's one airside paid lounge in Terminal 1, the “Convives de Marque” Lounge. <s>If you have a priority pass, you can [get access to the lounge](https://prioritypass.com/FR/Salons/Details-de-salon.cfm?loungecode=RAK). If you fly a lot with airlines where you don't have status / no such thing as status, then getting a Priority Pass can be a good idea. You can often find trials and discounts for new signups, and there are various financial products (eg high end credit cards, premium bank accounts) which will give you one. You mostly just need to think about how much you'll use it, to decide if you want one with a handful of inclusive lounge visits then pay-per-use after, or an unlimited one.</s> It used to be accessible through the Priority Pass lounge scheme, but they've recently stopped accepting it.

Alternately, it looks like you can [book access from the airport's website](http://www.onda.ma/en/Our-Airports/Marrakech-M%C3%A9nara-Airport/Services/%E2%80%9CConvives-de-marque%E2%80%9D-Lounge)

(An alternative to Priority Pass which allows you to book lounge visits without a subscription is [Lounge Buddy](http://www.loungebuddy.com/). They don't have the same range of lounges as Priority Pass, and sadly the “Convives de Marque” lounge isn't one of the ones they can currently sell you access to)

Answer (score 1):

Just for info for new readers with the same question:
The priority pass is no longer accepted at the Marrakech airport.